# MVC returns page as a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, postback

I have an mvc4 project and I am getting a weird result. Whenever I sumit a form and fire up a postback, if the entry is correct it redirects me to the success page which is good. But when my input is invalid and it has to return to the same page, to display the error message, it comes up as a downloadable file. Can anybody please tell me what is going on?

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Public Function Collection(oColInfo As CollectionInfoVM) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then
            oColInfo.CollectionDate = DateTime.Now
            m_oAppBase.Collection.AddGroupCollection(oColInfo)
            Return View("_Success")
        Else
            ViewData.Add("PaymentTypes", PaymentType.Dictionary.ToSelectList(oColInfo.PaymentType))
            ViewData.Add("PaidBy", PaidBy.Dictionary.ToSelectList(oColInfo.PaidBy.ToString()))

            Return View(oColInfo)
        End If
    End Function
```

**EDIT 1 :**

I also found out that my controller is returning my view as JSON. That's why IE is asking me if i wanted to download it. Why is my default return type JSON?

**EDIT 2 :**
The response type is application/json instead of text/html.

**EDIT 3 :**
It works when I remove the `Html.RenderAction("MainMenu", "Menu")` from my layout

Controller action looks like this;

```
Public Function MainMenu() As PartialViewResult
    ' Let's see if we have an unprocessed turnin from this district
    Dim dtDate As Date = DateTime.Now
    Dim colDistStatus As List(Of DistrictStatus) = m_oAppBase.TurnIn.GetNextTurnInStatus()
    ViewData.Add("DistrictStatus", colDistStatus)

    Return PartialView("_MainMenu")
End Function
```

Comment: It sounds like the mime type may be misconfigured

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so looking around I found out that there was a partial view on the page with  attribute that returns JSON and when I submit the button this get's fired up too and returned to the browser. I removed the HttpPost attribute and it fixed it. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my default return type JSON?

ActionResult includes JsonResult too.so when you use ActionResult and you post data from ajax ,your default returns Json.

> But when my input is invalid and it has to return to the same page

for validate form in client side,you have to use valid method in your script.it validates form in clientside and doesnt post to your action.

JqueryCode:

```
if ($('form').valid()) {
            $.ajax({});
                });
```